# Can we access facebook friends birthday's list in windows phone 7?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api

Please help me out the following scenario.

```
1.can we access the friends birthday's list using Graphic API in windows phone 7.
2.Can we access the friends updates message in windows phone 7.
```

please clarify me those are achieved or not.There is no Facebook API in windows phone 7.how to access the above ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access both by making the appropriate Graph API calls to the API endpoints. You just need to write a library that handles the OAuth and API calling for your App.

Calling https://graph.facebook.com/{friend_id} will return the user's DOB is you have requested the `friends_birthday` permission and their privacy settings are set to show their DOB. You can do something similar to get their status messages.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But you will have to code the Windows 7 Library to do it all.